# Why the webpages of my website are not appearing on deployment?

Tags: github, deployment, hosting, github-pages, website-deployment

I am deploying my react website through Github pages. Upon clicking on the deployed URL I am getting the following content (similar to github description of commands):

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://vats101.github.io/hack/",
  "name": "hack",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^1.8.8",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@firebase/app-compat": "^0.1.25",
    "@firebase/auth-compat": "^0.2.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "firebase": "^9.8.1",
    "framer-motion": "^6.3.3",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

My website link:
https://vats101.github.io/hack/

This is my App.js file where all routing is done:

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';

import {BrowserRouter as Router,Routes,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function App() {
  
  const [userName,setUserName]=useState(null);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' exact element={<><Homepage username={userName} setusername={setUserName} /></>}></Route>
        <Route path='/hack/' exact element={<><Homepage username={userName} setusername={setUserName} /></>}></Route>
        <!-- other routes also -->

      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Without seeing your code it will be impossible to help you. Please follow the guidelines in  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @tromgy There are too many files in my code,which code should I share. I have shared the App.js file here

Comment: I think your **package.json** would be more relevant as well as the folder structure of your project.

Comment: @tromgy I have added the files, can you check once now?

Comment: I see you got it all figured out? Your site looks all right now, no longer just the readme file.

Comment: @tromgy Ya but the routes are breaking..when someone clicks in community button it gives a 404 error.